# Django with numpy, Error:cannot import name multiarray

Tags: django, python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv

I'm running Django at a virtual environment targeting Python 3.4 using mod_wsgi. I have numpy 1.9 and I'm getting this error:

```
**Request Method:   GET
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
cannot import name multiarray
Exception Location: /var/www/mapsite/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/var/www/mapsite/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/var/www/mysite']
Server time:    Wed, 3 Dec 2014 09:07:24 +0000**
```

Plesae advice

Comment: Wait a second, why I see: `Python Version: 2.7.5` ?

Comment: No idea... I run apache and it is so

Comment: Did you set Python path of your virtual environment?

Comment: @user903772 same issue currently did you ever figure this out?

Comment: how did you install virtualenv? using pip or pip3..virtualenv isn't packaged for Python 3 yet so we have to use pip3

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you are in the right environment where you installed numpy, Django, etc. Base on your provided information, I'm assuming you have a virtualenv and currently developing your application. If the assumption is right, you can follow this steps.

You don't need Apache for this.

1. Source you virtualenv, `source /path/to/env/bin/activate` and go to you project directory.
2. Make sure you have all the package you need, `pip freeze` will show you, install if necessary.
3. Run the built in server from Django, `python manage.py runserver`
4. Go to your browser: `http://localhost:8000`

Voila !

Comment: Yes, you are right, but only useing manage.py to start web server. I have the same error message, but after start httpd(I'm sure that I have a virtualenv). Anyone can explain this?

Comment: "You don't need Apache" is a strong affirmation. I mean, if you don't want to have the site in production, yeah, no need for Apache. But if you want the site to be "production", then definitely run away from `runserver`.

Answer (score 0):

You should tweak your Apache and/or mod_wsgi configuration.

In the lines you show, one can see that a Python 2.7 is being used but is being combined with packages from a virtual environment of Python 3.4. That is completely wrong and should be addressed.

To fix that, the simplest way is to use the following python binary:

```
/var/www/mapsite/bin/python3.4
```

instead of the default

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Using the explicit virtual environment binary is the way to go in those situations (at least, it has worked for me in a lot of similar scenarios).